# Fading in a background on opening a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

Seems simple, but I can't get this to work with all the different methods I try.

All I want to do, is fade in an image from a black background when I open a new view controller.

So far I've tried this:

```
//I've set the image alpha to 0 on the storyboard already

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                          delay:0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         myImage.alpha = 1;

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];
    }
```

It runs, and the image comes up immediately (just doesn't seem to be animating!)
I know this is a simple question but I have already spent hours looking for a solution.
If anyone could help it would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation should work from within `-viewDidLoad` but you may be doing something more in `-viewDidLoad` that is disrupting the animation.
**or...**
You could instead move your animation code to `-viewDidAppear:`

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //do the animation here    
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, that was perfect :) It's always the simplest thing haha